# Derivative of Heaviside step Function

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Is this mathematically correct for a basic proof that the derivative of the Heaviside function is equal to the delta function? I don't know much about distributions so I kept everything integrated.

$$H(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x < 0\\\frac{1}{2} & x = 0\\1 & x>0\end{cases}$$
$$\delta (x) = \begin{cases}\infty & x = 0\\0 & x\neq 0\end{cases}$$

$$\forall a > 0$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta (x) \;dx = \int_{-\infty}^{a}\delta (x) \;dx = 1$$

$$\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^{a}H(x)\;dx = \frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^aH(x)\;dx = \frac{d}{da}\int_{0}^adx = 1$$

$$\therefore\frac{d}{da}\int_{-\infty}^{a}H(x)\;dx = \int_{-\infty}^{a}\delta (x) \;dx $$

Comment: No. You need to define rigorously $\delta(x)$. You'll obtain that if $\varphi$ is $C^1$ and compactly supported, integrating by parts gives
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}H(x) \varphi(x)dx = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(x) \varphi'(x)dx =  \varphi(0)$$
Which proves that $\frac{d}{dx} H(x) = \delta(x)$ as distributions. Otherwise, from $\delta(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1_{|x| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon}$ you can show that $\int_{-\infty}^x \delta(y)dy =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1_{|y| < \epsilon}}{2 \epsilon}dy =H(x)$

Comment: The Delta function is **not** a function. Nothing correct can come out of treating it as one.

Comment: The $\texttt{Heaviside Step function}$ $\mathrm{H}$ isn't defined at $x = 0$. Namely, $\mathrm{H}:\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{\,{0}\,\right\} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @felix, that is a matter of convention. It is often defined at 0 to be 1/2 for reasons related to the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 7):

A distribution is a linear functional on a space of "nice" functions, e.g. $C_c^\infty$, infinitely differentiable functions with compact support. The application of a distribution $u$ on a nice function $\phi$ is often written $\langle u, \phi \rangle$.

The derivative of a distribution is defined by $\langle u', \phi \rangle := - \langle u, \phi' \rangle$. This formula is motivated by integration by parts, $\int f'(x) \, \phi(x) \, dx = - \int f(x) \, \phi'(x) \, dx$ when $\phi(x) = 0$ for big $|x|$.

These definitions give, for any smooth $\phi$ which vanishes at infinity,
$$
\langle H', \phi \rangle 
= - \langle H, \phi' \rangle
= - \int H(x) \, \phi'(x) \, dx
= - \int_0^\infty \phi'(x) \, dx \\
= - \left( \phi(\infty) - \phi(0) \right)
= \phi(0)
= \langle \delta, \phi \rangle
.$$

Since this is valid for all nice $\phi$ we have $H' = \delta$.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkViola. I wobbled a bit whether I should write $\phi(\infty)$ but thought that it's clear enough even if it's not totally mathematically correct.

Comment: In the step where -$\int H(x) \phi'(x)dx$ becomes $-\int_0^\infty \phi'(x)dx$, why does the fact $H(0)=1/2$ *not* matter?

Comment: @lineage. When taking integrals, the value at a single point doesn't matter. If you for example let $f(x)=x$ except for $f(0)=1$ you still have $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx=0.$